# How can I decode a base64 string from the command line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to write a bash script to decode a base64 string. For example I type `decode QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==` and it prints `Aladdin:open sesame` and returns to the prompt.

So far I have tried a simple bash file containing `python -m base64 -d $1` but this command expects a filename not a string. Is there another non-interactive command (not necessarily in a Python module) that I can run from the command line to achieve this, without having to install any extra packages? (Or if I do, something super-minimal.)

Comment: Nice question. And thanks for your hint, I now know the `python -m base64 -h` can become handy.

Answer (score 967, accepted):

Just use the `base64` program from the `coreutils` package:

```
echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode
```

Or, to include the newline character

```
echo `echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode`
```

output (includes newline):

```
Aladdin:open sesame
```

Comment: Or: echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode && echo

Comment: Or: `base64 -d <<< QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`

Comment: `echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\base64" --decode 2> nul > example.txt` On Windows with git's base64.

Comment: @January It is not `Just use`, because many people know about the `base64` program – but as one can't *just* insert a string as command line option, it is hard to get the syntax right for users who touch the CLI only once in a while.

Comment: On Mac, copy the the encoded string into clipboard and run `pbpaste | base64 --decode`.

Comment: There might be `\n` in the decoded string so you probably want to do `echo -e`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467448/435605)

Comment: If for some reason you do not wish to have new lines in the encoded string, use the option `-w 0` when encoding. I like this as it makes it easier to decode at the shell.

Comment: This is a bad method when the string contains special characters such as `$` or `!`

Answer (score 131):

openssl can also encode and decode base64

```
$ openssl enc -base64 <<< 'Hello, World!'
SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=
$ openssl enc -base64 -d <<< SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=
Hello, World!
```

EDIT: An example where the base64 encoded string ends up on multiple lines:

```
$ openssl enc -base64 <<< 'And if the data is a bit longer, the base64 encoded data will span multiple lines.'
QW5kIGlmIHRoZSBkYXRhIGlzIGEgYml0IGxvbmdlciwgdGhlIGJhc2U2NCBlbmNv
ZGVkIGRhdGEgd2lsbCBzcGFuIG11bHRpcGxlIGxpbmVzLgo=
$ openssl enc -base64 -d << EOF
> QW5kIGlmIHRoZSBkYXRhIGlzIGEgYml0IGxvbmdlciwgdGhlIGJhc2U2NCBlbmNv
> ZGVkIGRhdGEgd2lsbCBzcGFuIG11bHRpcGxlIGxpbmVzLgo=
> EOF
And if the data is a bit longer, the base64 encoded data will span multiple lines.
```

Comment: Thanks to Philippe's answer, you need to add -A for long base64 strings otherwise openssl will return nothing, see http://askubuntu.com/a/271676/305568

Comment: @morloch or just avoid removing the newlines from the base64 encoded data, and it works as expected...

Comment: I would not consider `coreutils` an "additional" package containing programs like `ls`, `mkdir`, `cp`, `mv`, and `chmod`. I doubt you can do anything useful with your machine without it.

Comment: @vidstige, that's true. I don't know why I was under the impression that base64 was not installed by default; that is totally not the case.

Comment: While this is the ubuntu stack exchange, using `openssl` has the advantage over standard `base64` of working in Git Bash on Windows, at least the older 1.8.1 Git Bash version I have installed.

Answer (score 51):

Here you go!

Add the following to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
decode () {
  echo "$1" | base64 -d ; echo
}
```

Now, open a new Terminal and run the command.

```
decode QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

This will do exactly what you asked for in your question.

Answer (score 25):

With your original dependencies it is possible to do this with a minor modification to your original script:

```
echo $1 | python -m base64 -d
```

If you don't pass a file name, that python module reads from the standard input. To pipe the first parameter into it you can use `echo $1 |`.

Comment: Also: python -m base32 filename

Comment: this does not work :) but use .b32* methods

Answer (score 21):

I did comment base64 command line in http://wiki.opensslfoundation.com/index.php?title=Command_Line_Utilities. 
So I issue a Warning when using openssl base64 decoding :

```
 openssl base64 -e <<< 'Welcome to openssl wiki'

 V2VsY29tZSB0byBvcGVuc3NsIHdpa2kK



openssl base64 -d <<< 'V2VsY29tZSB0byBvcGVuc3NsIHdpa2kK'

Welcome to openssl wiki
```

warning **base64 line length is limited to 64 characters by default in openssl** :

```
 openssl base64 -e <<< 'Welcome to openssl wiki with a very long line
 that splits...'

 V2VsY29tZSB0byBvcGVuc3NsIHdpa2kgd2l0aCBhIHZlcnkgbG9uZyBsaW5lIHRo
 YXQgc3BsaXRzLi4uCg==

openssl base64 -d <<< 'V2VsY29tZSB0byBvcGVuc3NsIHdpa2kgd2l0aCBhIHZlcnkgbG9uZyBsaW5lIHRoYXQgc3BsaXRzLi4uCg=='
```

=> NOTHING !

to be able to decode a base64 line without line feed that exceed 64 characters use -A option :

```
openssl base64 -d -A <<<
'V2VsY29tZSB0byBvcGVuc3NsIHdpa2kgd2l0aCBhIHZlcnkgbG9uZyBsaW5lIHRoYXQgc3BsaXRzLi4uCg=='

Welcome to openssl wiki with a very long line that splits...
```

This is anyway better to actualy split base64 result in 64 characters lines since -A option is BUGGY ( limit with long files ).

Comment: openssl wiki documentation was moved here https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities#Base64_Encoding_Strings then a rewrtie of did lost this -A usage and 64 characters limits.

Answer (score 8):

Using `perl`

```
perl -MMIME::Base64 -ne 'printf "%s\n",decode_base64($_)' <<< "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="
```

Or the same with `python`

```
python -m base64 -d <<< "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another way to do it:

```
emacs -Q --batch  -eval '(princ (base64-encode-string (read-string ": ")))'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a few moments of hair-pulling on this one because the `base64` Linux tool and also the `openssl` can decode, indeed. But I have this particular base64 encoded file that decodes to slightly wrong value. The few bytes do match, but then there is this presence of `EF BF BD EF BF BD` when I view in `hexedit` viewer. And then the next sequence of bytes match again when compared to the correctly decoded expected output. These weird sequence of bytes got inserted in the in-betweens, sometime as `EF BF BD` only.

To resolve the matter, I have to look how the Java sender encodes it and then I created a small java base64 decoder. And now I can decoded to the expected value.

Here is the small snippet that does it: https://gist.github.com/typelogic/0567cdab6c15487c31496cb90006ff52