# How to convert python file from compress base64?

Tags: python

I have python file lie this

```
import marshal
exec(marshal.loads(base64.b64decode('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')))
```

How to convert to normal string file ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run this through almost any Base64 decoder, including [ones available online](https://www.base64decode.com/). Alternatively, [this answer from almost 10 years ago showing how to decode from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/178546/1222991) is still quite valid:

```
echo QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== | base64 --decode
```

Comment: Already I have tried what you advice but nothings help ... I have got this ```cBs$|dj�dd}|dUdS(NRLii(Rp(R7tZZ((s<strng>R!�scCs�|dj�}|dkr�|dj�|dj�|dj�|dj�|dj�|j�|d j�| ``` not correct codes

Comment: the original code is ike this ``` import base64
exec base64.b64decode('aW1wb3J0IG1hcnNoYWwKZXhlYyhtYXJzaGFsLmxvYWRzKGJhc2U2NC5iNjRkZWNvZGUoJ1l3QUFBQUFBQUFBQUF3QUFBRUFBQUF')```` .... and after i convert it I have got like ```import marshal
exec(marshal.loads(base64.b64decode('YwAAAAAAAAAAAwAAAEAAAABzbAQAAGQAAGQBAGwAAG0BAFoBAAFkA')```

Comment: The correctness of the output is outside the scope of the question. You supplied what was advertised as a Base64-encoded string. If the output is incomplete, that’s on the source of the string. Pasting it into Base64decode.com does offer *some* accurate-looking strings, but I will not invest any time in cleaning up what could be an incomplete string 

Comment: How can I upload the complete code ?!! I can not because the post have limit characters

Answer (score 0):

I found this coe from some of my friends. And work fine

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# collect By Aime_jeux
###########################################################################
import marshal,base64,zlib
import sys
from sys import stdout
from uncompyle6.main import decompile
import py_compile
###########################################################################
def main():
        FileSource = '/home/user/Desktop/plugin.py'
        ############################## READ FILE ###################################
        fileR = open(FileSource, 'r')
        text = fileR.read()
        fileR.close()
        ############################## CLEAR TXT_FILE ##############################
        TxT = text.replace('import base64\nexec(base64.b64decode(','').replace('))','')
        _Dons = base64.b64decode(TxT)
        _Dons = _Dons.replace('import marshal\n','').replace('exec(marshal.loads(','').replace(')))','').replace('base64.b64decode(','')
        ############################## DECOMPRES TXT_FILE WITH MARSHAL #############
        _Dons =  marshal.loads(base64.b64decode(_Dons))
        #_Donns = decompile(2.7, _Dons,stdout)
        ############################## OUT FILE ####################################
        OutPutFile = '/home/user/Desktop/MyFileOut.py'
        F = file(OutPutFile,"w")
        F.write(decompile(2.7, _Dons,stdout).text)
        F.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
     main()
```